# How I can use ThenInclude in Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have problem with using of `ThenInclude` to get high level entities from db. How to change `GetAll` method to do this?

```cs
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    internal DbSet<T> dbSet;
    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
        this.dbSet = _db.Set<T>();
    }   

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(string? includeProperties = null)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(includeProperties))
        {
            foreach (var property in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(property);
            }
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

I'm beginner, sorry if the question is stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches.

The first one is to make your repository specific for each entity type. That way you can include whatever properties makes sense for that specific type. This seem to be the model recommended by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implementation-entity-framework-core).

You can use a generic repository, but it should probably be a base class for your entity specific repository. That way you can stuff common things in the generic base class, while implementing anything entity specific, like includes, in the derived class.

Another way could be to let your `GetAll`-method take a  `Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> includeDecorator`. But I would probably not recommend this as I think it moves to much responsibility and complexity to the caller.